# GCC warns about order of initialization not matching the order of declaration

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor

Following code:

```
class C
{
    int a, b;
public:
    C()
    :b(0), a(0)
    {}
};
```

Causes GCC to complain about wrong order of initialization. Specifically:

```
../AppSrc/MainForm.cpp: In constructor 'C::C()':
../AppSrc/MainForm.cpp:51:9: warning: 'C::b' will be initialized after
../AppSrc/MainForm.cpp:51:6: warning:   'int C::a'
```

What's the big deal here, why the whining? It's not like there is, or could potentially be, an interdependency between members. Primitives, duh.

Oh, and how do I turn this warning off or at least make it less aggressive?

EDIT: there are many ways to shoot yourself in the foot in C++; member interdependency is one of them. I'm aware of that and I avoid that anyway, just like I would avoid null pointer dereferencing.

Arbitrary init order can be perfectly safe, just like in the snippet above. I'm unhappy about compiler not recognizing such cases and complaining anyway. I mean, it does not complain about every single pointer dereference that is not immediately preceeded by a null check, does it?

Comment: The simplest and the most robust way to silence this particular warning is to put the members and their initializations in the same order.

Comment: Definitely not the simplest, considering the amount of legacy code that compiled without a hitch under different compilers/settings.

Comment: Fixing incorrect code is always a good thing, even when the code is only *slightly* incorrect. After all, your company does have junior programmers, doesn't it?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, the issue is that the init order is not arbitrary, it's defined by the order of the variable declaration. It doesn't matter what order you specify in the initializer list, it is completely ignored.  So it's not complaining you are doing something not safe, it's warning you that it's essentially changing what you've written.

Comment: Now I get it. Make an answer.

Answer (score 8):

In this particular example, the warning can be safely ignored. If they depended on each other, you'd have an issue. You can turn it off with `-Wno-reorder`.

**But** better re-order them. It might not make a difference to the compiler, but you'll get in the habit of initializing members in the order in which they appear, which is a good thing.

Comment: If they depended on each other, I'd put the init-first one into the base, so that proper initialization order is guaranteed. Bad practice all around, those interdependencies. I'd rather have the compiler whine about that.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, I don't understand why you're against this warning. The C++ standard allows something it probably shouldn't and GCC is detecting this for you. Usually when you see an initilization list you assume it is handled in the order it appears, but in this case it will actually be reordered on you. It seems like a good thing to know when the compiler is reordering your initialization.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I think the op know this, he wants to get rid of the warning. He appears to know the implications.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - DO NOT IGNORE WARNINGS - THERE MAY BE A CLIFF AHEAD.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not like there is, or could potentially be, an interdependency between members. Primitives, duh.

Erm, unless someone changes it:

```
class C
{
  int a, b;
public:
  C()
  :b(a), a(0)
  {}
};
```

Most people think it's better to get a warning about that *before* the problem happens, so they can fix the code. You seem to be in a minority who want to leave the code intentionally flawed and complain about the compiler.

> Arbitrary init order can be perfectly safe, just like in the snippet above.

The point is the order of initialization isn't arbitrary, it's always in the order the members are declared, and some of us want to be warned when we write mem-initializers in the wrong order.

> I'm unhappy about compiler not recognizing such cases and complaining anyway.

If you don't like the warning turn it off, how to do that is in the documentation (and in an earlier answer, so you don't even have to look far ;-)

Comment: I've been working with C++ for 15+ years. Now is the first time I see a compiler complaining. Wasn't that big a deal in the not so distant past, was it? Rather, YOU were the one expected to be watching out for interdependencies and order-of-init issues.

Answer (score 0):

The is a **VERY** big reason for the **whining**, See *Scott Myers* book *Effective C++* Item 13 page 57 for details.

Or as he puts it on page 58:

```
class Wacko {
   public:
      Wacko(const char *s): s1(s), s2(0) {}
      Wacko(const Wacko &rhs): s2(rhs.s1), s1(0) {}
   private:
      string s1, s2;
};

Wacko w1 = "Hello World!";
Wacko w2 = w1;
```

Is `w2` the same as `w1`?